# javascript IE 8 bug

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I keep on getting this particular error in the code

Object doesn't support this action

What does this mean "Object doesn't support this action" ???

```
attachEvent = function(state){
                if(state == 'up'){
                    slideUp();
                    return false;
                }
                if(state == 'down'){
                    slideDown();
                    return false;
                }
                $(up).click(function(){
                    slideUp();
                });
                $(down).click(function(){
                    slideDown();
                });
            }
```

Comment: `window.attachEvent` is defined in IE, and read-only.

Answer (score 1):

Without using `var`, your code will attempt to assign a value to a property called `attachEvent` in the global object. The global object is `window` in browsers, so this attempted assignment fails in IE because there is a pre-existing, read-only `window.attachEvent` method.

The easiest fix is to use `var`:

```
var attachEvent = function(state) {
    // Stuff
};
```